# How to create a temporary table with rows from a table, but only using the rows that did not match

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I have a table named 'Position' that it has six rows, with id's 1,2,3,4,5 y 6 respectively.
Using a script, i created a temporary table that it has two rows, with rows from 'Position', having only id's 5 y 6 respectively.

What i need to do, is to create a new temporary table, but only that it has the rows from 'Position' with id's 1,2,3 y 4.

Anyone know's how to do this?

I tried this:

```
SELECT p.[Id] as idPosicion
      ,[CantidadMaximaApilados]
      ,[IdZona]
into #PosicionesRemover
  FROM [Posicion] p -- this is the table with id's 1,2,3,4,5 y 6
  inner join View_ContenedoresEnStock v ON p.Id = v.posicionId

select * from #PosicionesRemover -- this is the temporary table that only has id's 5 y 6

SELECT P.Id, P.CantidadMaximaApilados, P.IdZona INTO #PosicionesNoOcupadas FROM Posicion P
left join #PosicionesRemover R ON R.idPosicion = P.Id -- here is when i try to only left rows with id's 1,2,3 y 4
```

Comment: Use a `WHERE` clause, add to your query, `WHERE P.Id < 5`

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to create a temporary table:

```
SELECT p.[Id] as idPosicion
      ,[CantidadMaximaApilados]
      ,[IdZona]
INTO #PosicionesRemover
FROM [Posicion] p -- this is the table with id's 1,2,3,4,5 y 6
INNER JOIN View_ContenedoresEnStock v ON p.Id = v.posicionId

SELECT * FROM #PosicionesRemover

SELECT P.Id, P.CantidadMaximaApilados, P.IdZona 
INTO #PosicionesNoOcupadas 
FROM [Posicion] P
LEFT JOIN #PosicionesRemover R ON R.idPosicion = P.Id
WHERE R.idPosicion IS NULL
```

Otherwise you can just do:

```
SELECT P.Id, P.CantidadMaximaApilados, P.IdZona 
INTO #PosicionesNoOcupadas 
FROM Posicion P
LEFT JOIN View_ContenedoresEnStock v ON P.Id = v.posicionId
WHERE v.posicionId IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to be done in a single statement:

```
    SELECT p.[Id] as idPosicion
        ,[CantidadMaximaApilados]
        ,[IdZona]
    into #PosicionesRemoverNEW
    FROM [Posicion] p -- this is the table with id's 1,2,3,4,5 y 6
      inner join View_ContenedoresEnStock v ON p.Id = v.posicionId
    WHERE p.[Id]<5
```